# Get the most left X and the most right X from the AmXYChart

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

Let's say we have a AmXYChart as one below. [image]
How can I automatically get coordinates of the most left and the most right X values? For example in our case it will be  1 and 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get min/max of value axis by accessing min and max properties. Note, you can do that only after chart is rendered: http://jsfiddle.net/qGe47/1/

`getAxisBounds = function(){
    console.log(chart.valueAxes[0].min + " " + chart.valueAxes[0].max);
    console.log(chart.valueAxes[1].min + " " + chart.valueAxes[1].max);
}`

Comment: yeah, I saw that. Unfortunately I needed those values before chart rendering.